# Migrating my data from MongoDB Atlas

Tags: database, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've recently had a lot of weird usage between my MongoDB instance hosted on Atlas and my AWS instance hosting the application that uses the db. That's why i thought about hosting MongoDB on my own AWS server.

Since then i've tried to find tutorials on how to migrate my data from Atlas to my own setup, but haven't found anything but tutorials to migrate from something else to Atlas (which is obv not what i want)

Is there some standard way im just not seeing, being fairly inexperienced with the low level MongoDB stuff, or are they actively keeping this quiet?

I'd really appreciate some help because i'm hosting a hobby project and the most costs are created from network costs for moving data between my AWS instance and Atlas.

Comment: Is it not as simple as running `mongodump` to get a dump file of the Atlas database, then running `mongorestore` to load that data into a DB you have setup on AWS? Although, if you are uncomfortable or unfamiliar with setting up an EC2 server and managing backups of your DB yourself, I would stick with Atlas or try MLab instead, since both of those run on EC2. Are you sure you are running your MongoDB instance and your AWS instance in the same AWS region currently?

Comment: Thanks, i honestly didnt know mongodump. The costs from Atlas, as ive found out, seem to be costs for their internal communication between clusters, back ups and stat retrieval. (Many others seem to get random costs too) i will probably just dump all the Data into my own instance because for this project money>data

Comment: Please note that Atlas allows you to easily LIVE migrate INTO their service but will not allow you to do the same in case you wish to leave them (or simply keep a read only node for your own usage). Seems quite evil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've recently had a lot of weird usage between my MongoDB instance hosted on Atlas and my AWS instance hosting the application that uses the db. That's why i thought about hosting MongoDB on my own AWS server.

In addition to the hourly hosting cost, [MongoDB Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas) also passed on the cloud provider charges for data transfer traffic between cluster nodes. The data transfer includes: replica set monitoring, heartbeats, automation, and back-ups.

See also:

- [MongoDB Atlas Pricing](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas/pricing)
- [Billing: data transfer](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/billing/#data-transfer)
- [Billing: backup](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/billing/#backup)

> i'm hosting a hobby project and the most costs are created from network costs for moving data between my AWS instance and Atlas

Depending on your use case requirements, you can try [MongoDB Atlas Free Tier](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/atlas-free-tier-setup/) instead. Note that this tier has lower specifications and some [limitations](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/free-shared-limitations/) compared to the paid tier.

To answer your question, you can export data from MongoDB Atlas using [mongodump](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/). See also:

- [Back Up and Restore with MongoDB Tools](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/backup-and-restore-tools/)
- [Restore a Replica Set from MongoDB Backups](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/restore-replica-set-from-backup/)

Alternatively, if you have enabled the continuous back-up feature, you can use MongoDB Atlas’s restore capabilities to generate a copy of your database for your own use, including seeding a new environment you manage yourself.

Comment: To your pricing Standpoint, it seems they are just plain lying, because [others have this happen to them too](https://forums.meteor.com/t/my-experience-with-mongodb-atlas-high-data-transfer-usage/37772/7). I also already usw the free tier, which is why i really don't want to get billed for it. Thanks for the mongodump and Backup links, i will probably host it myself anyways.

Comment: @SebastianDiLuzio, I've edited the answer to reflect the correct pricing including data transfers after more research. thanks

Comment: Be aware that you cannot do a LIVE migration out of Atlas. That is quite an issue for keeping your environment up 24x7. It seems like Atlas are hiding this from people so please beware before trying their service.